# How do I batch update a standard custom field for event participants?

Tags: civievent

I have lots of profiles which allow me to batch update records. All of the profiles show as an option when I have used a normal contact search to identify individuals. However, when I search for event participants very few batch update profiles are available. The Civibook says: If you wish to update participant fields, you must do the update from a Find Participants search (and only include participant fields in your profile).

The fields I want to update for event participants are normal custom fields which weren't created for or linked to a specific event. Is it possible to include these fields in a profile which then shows up as an option when I choose Batch Update for event participants? (I tried to add some of these fields to a current profile which showed up for event participants but after I'd added them the profile disappeared from the list!)

My current workaround is to select event participants, create a new smart group and then use that smart group with my multiple batch update profiles. It's fine but adds another layer of work when dealing with tens of different events. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the description of your custom fields as "normal custom fields" and your current workaround, it seems that the fields you want to update are contact custom fields rather than participant custom fields.

If that is so, then do an **Advanced Search** specifying criteria in the **Events** section rather than a **Find Participants** search. On the results page you will have the option to **Batch Update via Profiles**. Select that option and all your profiles should appear in the selection list.